# Controlling the execution order of clean up function relative to async requests in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, indexeddb

In an indexedDB database transaction, there are multiple `add`, `get`, and `put` requests inside a `try-catch`.  An issue that arises in attempting to protect the program from failing, even if a user tampers with the data externally, is that when one of the requests errors, the error events of all the requests are fired and bubble up to the transaction error event, such that the code in `transaction.onerror` runs multiple times.  This is handled by declaring a boolean variable as false and then setting it to true in `transaction.onerror` and testing against it in each `request.onerror` function and, if true, executing `evt.stopPropagation()`.

This works except for one small problem.  To guard against the potential of memory leaks, all variables in the database function are set to null by invoking an internal function, freeRAM(), at the end of `transaction.oncomplete` and `transaction.onerror`.  Since the `transaction.onerror` function can be executed before all the requests are made, the freeRAM() function can set all variables to null, causing other requests to fail that would've run successfully and, since the boolean variable is also cleared, the technique used to stop subsequent request errors from bubbling to `transaction.onerror` fails because that variable is null at the point.

My question is, is there a way to execute freeRAM() after all requests have either succeeded or errored?  Will a `setTimeout` on freeRAM() ensure that it goes on the stack after all the requests have completed?

In testing, placing an alert message indicating a database error in the `transaction.onerror` function just before executing freeRAM() gives the requests time to complete; but I would like a better method.  I understand that I could simply not set 'error' and other related variables to null, but I'd like to know if the execution of freeRAM() can be set to always take place after all the requests have completed.

I tried using `setTimeout( free_RAM, 0 )` in place of `alert` and it appears to work but I'm not certain if it will always execute freeRAM() after the requests complete or if it is just working for my tests.  Perhaps, a custom message that executes freeRAM() after the user clicks 'OK' will be adequate or adding more time to the `setTimeout`.  These are short transactions, requests write a small amount of data.

Code is below. Thank you.

```
  error = false;
  T.onerror = ( v ) =>
    {
      v.stopPropagation(); // Stop propagation up to the database error level in the database open block.
      if ( !error ) 
        {
          error = true; 
          // Next two statements must execute only once.
          if ( m ) { Q.max = key - 1; } else { Q.gap.push(key); };
          if ( log ) undo_rollbackKey( qst_undo );
          alert( 'bad data' ); // If this is removed, program fails for bad data.
          free_RAM(); // Sets all variables, including 'error' to null;
        }; // end if
      v = null;
    }; // close T.onerror

    // Within the try-catch is code like this, involving 'error'.
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
      { 
        req_a = q.add( { 'k' : k[i], 'c' : d, 'e' : d, 'E' : [] } );
        req_a.onerror = ( evt ) => { if ( error ) evt.stopPropagation(); }; 
      }; // next i

    req_b = q.add( { 'k' : [ key, 3, 0 ], 'g' : [], 'm' : 0, 'q' : [], 'N' : '', 'P' : '' } );
    req_b.onerror = ( evt ) => { if ( error ) evt.stopPropagation(); };
```

UPDATE: I'm still working through this but It appears that an answer to my issue is to use `transaction.onabort` rather than `onerror` because it appears every request error does not bubble to `transaction.onabort` but only to `transaction.onerror`, such that `onabort` fires only once at most. However, I'm not certain that invoking freeRAM() from `transaction.onabort` won't still take place before the rest of the requests error; but that may not be an issue because all the `request.onerror` functions won't be needed any longer since their only purpose is to stop propagation after the first bubbling to `transaction.onerror`.  After experimenting I will modify this update.  Also this [link](https://javascript.info/indexeddb) provides some information on indexedDB that I have not come across on MDN.  It doesn't answer this question but appears useful.  Perhaps, the 'Promise wrapper' section of the mentioned link will be useful if this approach does not work.

AFTER FURTHER TESTING: Thus far, the use of `transaction.abort` in place of `transaction.onerror` with the removal of all `request.onerror` handlers has resulted in no failures due to invoking freeRAM() too early, before all requests have completed.  Still needed a `T.onerror = ( v ) => { v.stopPropagation(); };` to stop the errors from bubbling up to the database `onerror` handler.  I've been unable to generate a failure.  I tried repeating a unique key in an early `add` request in attempting to get it to error and invoke `transaction.onabort` before the other requests completed that used variables set to null by freeRAM(), and there was no failure. I'm not sure this is full proof and do not understand why `transaction.abort` could not invoke freeRAM() before the later requests are made and cause an error.

I should say that I understand why all the requests in the code above are made before the abort handler executes; but there is also a `get` request that, on success, updates values in the result and then makes a `put` request.  The updating of the result uses variables set to null by freeRAM(); and an early request error for attempting to add a duplicate unique key would possibly invoke the abort handler before the update of the get request completed; at least that was taking place when used `transaction.onerror`.  The code example is below.  If I cause an error in the loop at i=1 to add a duplicate key, there is not a failure due to the req.onsuccess handler for using a variable set to null by freeRAM(), Q in this example.  This was taking place when using only `transaction.onerror`.  Whether or not this set up is full proof against a user tampering with data externally, I don't know; but I haven't figured out how to break it yet.

The variable 'error' isn't really needed in this set up, except it is used in the `catch` which has `if ( !error ) T.abort()`.  So, if make the code in T.onabort a function, then could get rid of 'error' altogether and just invoke the same function from the `catch`; but that might not work if there are two errors: such as a database error and an error that causes a request to not be made.  One causes an abort and the other is handled by the catch, causing the code to be executed twice.  So, perhaps, it is best to keep the T.abort() in the catch and use 'error' variable. Thank you for any suggestion you may be able to provide.

This work, although fairly frustrating at first, has been quite interesting.  One important step that I missed up to this point is that an additional try-catch is required within the `req.onsuccess` handler and the `catch` must abort the transaction.  Otherwise, a non-database error will result in all the other data being written to the database except the final `put` in the onsuccess handler.  The outer try-catch, at least in Firefox, won't catch the error within the `req.onsuccess` handler.  A true database error within the onsuccess handler will still abort the transaction.  Catching errors is a bit trickier than I expected, at least for a novice like myself.

```
  let Q = { /* Object data */ },
      error = false;

  function freeRAM() { Q = error = null; }

  T.onerror = ( v ) => { v.stopPropagation(); };
  T.onabort = ( v ) =>
    {
      v.stopPropagation();
      if ( !error ) 
        {
          error = true; 
          // Next two statements must execute only once.
          if ( m ) { Q.max = key - 1; } else { Q.gap.push(key); };
          if ( log ) undo_rollbackKey( qst_undo );
          free_RAM(); // Sets all variables, including 'error' to null;
        }; // end if
      v = null;
    }; // close T.onerror

    try {
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
      { q.add( { 'k' : k[i], 'c' : d, 'e' : d, 'E' : [] } ); }; 

    req = q.get( [ 0, 0, 0 ] );
    req.onsuccess = function() 
      {
        let r;
        try {
          if ( req.result )
           {
             r = req.result;
             /* Update r using variable set to null by freeRAM() */
             r.m = Q.max;
             q.put( r ); 
            }; // end if
          }
         catch(e) { if ( !error ) T.abort(); }
         finally { r = null; }             
      }; // close req.onsuccess
    } // close try
    catch { if ( !error ) T.abort(); }
```